# Need help changing column datatype from characters to datetime

Tags: r

I am trying to bind rows together but there are conflicting datatypes.
I need to change the datatypes of these columns from character to datetime with y-m-d h:m:s format.

```
m5_2021 <- m5_2021 %>%
    mutate(across(c(started_at, ended_at), parse_date))
m6_2021 <- m6_2021 %>%
    mutate(across(c(started_at, ended_at), parse_date))
m12_2021 <- m12_2021 %>%
    mutate(across(c(started_at, ended_at), parse_date))
```

I tried doing this, but it cuts out the seconds from the columns- which I need. Thanks

edit: added the output of `str(m5_2021)`

```
spec_tbl_df [531,633 × 13] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ ride_id           : chr [1:531633] "C809ED75D6160B2A" "DD59FDCE0ACACAF3" "0AB83CB88C43EFC2" "7881AC6D39110C60" ...
 $ rideable_type     : chr [1:531633] "electric_bike" "electric_bike" "electric_bike" "electric_bike" ...
 $ started_at        : chr [1:531633] "30/05/2021 11:58" "30/05/2021 11:29" "30/05/2021 14:24" "30/05/2021 14:25" ...
 $ ended_at          : chr [1:531633] "30/05/2021 12:10" "30/05/2021 12:14" "30/05/2021 14:25" "30/05/2021 14:41" ...
 $ start_station_name: chr [1:531633] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ start_station_id  : chr [1:531633] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ end_station_name  : chr [1:531633] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ end_station_id    : chr [1:531633] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ start_lat         : num [1:531633] 41.9 41.9 41.9 41.9 41.9 ...
 $ start_lng         : num [1:531633] -87.6 -87.6 -87.7 -87.7 -87.7 ...
 $ end_lat           : num [1:531633] 41.9 41.8 41.9 41.9 41.9 ...
 $ end_lng           : num [1:531633] -87.6 -87.6 -87.7 -87.7 -87.7 ...
 $ member_casual     : chr [1:531633] "casual" "casual" "casual" "casual" ...
 - attr(*, "spec")=
  .. cols(
  ..   ride_id = col_character(),
  ..   rideable_type = col_character(),
  ..   started_at = col_character(),
  ..   ended_at = col_character(),
  ..   start_station_name = col_character(),
  ..   start_station_id = col_character(),
  ..   end_station_name = col_character(),
  ..   end_station_id = col_character(),
  ..   start_lat = col_double(),
  ..   start_lng = col_double(),
  ..   end_lat = col_double(),
  ..   end_lng = col_double(),
  ..   member_casual = col_character()
  .. )
 - attr(*, "problems")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: use `lubridate::ymd_hms` function

Comment: I'm sorry, but what would that look like?
I tried 
```
m5_2021<- ymd_hms(m5_2021$started_at)
```
, but it says that the $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.

Comment: the error is regarding `m5_2021$started_at` and has nothing to do with the function `lubridate::ymd_hms`

Comment: This would be easier if you showed us what your data looks like. Paste the result of `dput(m5_2021)` into your question.

Comment: Hi, `dput(m5_2021)` took too long to compute, so I added `str(m5_2021)` instead. Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue by using `dmy_hms` instead of `ymd_hms`.